What could the strange noise in the images be due to? They appear to be composed of 8x8 squares, and many of them contain different patterns
The question may seem silly, but I am curious about the structure of images from a certain biomedical image dataset.

If you enlarge the following image fragments, you can see that they consist of 8x8 pixel squares and many of these squares contain different patterns, e.g., stripes or grid-like.
I have not found any information regarding the sensor that was used in the camera by which the images were collected. I only have a catalog note:
KOWA V10 Alpha specifications
This puzzles me all the more because I have not encountered such a thing in any dataset. Sadly, such an image structure makes my work a bit difficult, as I have to implement detection of very small objects on it, which occupy areas sometimes of a dozen by a dozen pixels. After preprocessing, such structure becomes even more prominent (another sample preprocessed fragment is included below below), which I think lowers the performance of the system.

I would appreciate any hints about the reason for this type of image structure.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about Electrical Engineering.

"8x8 squares" makes me think you're looking at JPEG compression artifacts.

@brhans Indeed, the creators of the database have provided this dataset in .jpeg format. I thought this was an issue resulting from the sensor. Anyway, thanks for help. I would not have come across the fact that such artifacts appear during compression.

Indeed, not an EE question. However, one working with medical imaging has to be aware about what file formats are suitable and what are unsuitable for storing or deliverin information. For example lossy compression may mask away details or enhance noise in image, leaving something undiagnosed in time or causing false positives. For same reason JPEG is completely wrong for X-ray images etc, listening music through MP3 compression can be heard, as well as watching terrestial/cable TV via digital compression, you can't see anything else than compression artifacts when there is a lot of movement.

@Justme Surprisingly this is one of the most widely used datasets in this subfield, but the author have not made the dataset available in any format other than .jpeg. Thanks

From what you've shared, I'd guess the image is most likely stored as JPEG. Without digging deeper, this encoding (and thus the artifacts) may be introduced anywhere in the chain - from the equipment itself, to the tools used to prepare the datasheet. It may even be re-encoded multiple times before you see it, reducing in quality each time.
The 8x8 pixel patterns you're seeing are most likely from the 64 options shown in "The Ultimate Guide to JPEG Including JPEG Compression & Encoding" and other details on this topic.


This puzzles me all the more because I have not encountered such a thing in any dataset.

It's not clear from your writing, but if you're using the same equipment and not seeing these artifacts, then it's more likely that they are introduced later in the chain - i.e: while preparing documentation, and not by the equipment itself.

Sadly, such an image structure makes my work a bit difficult, as I have to implement detection of very small objects on it, which occupy areas sometimes of a dozen by a dozen pixels.

Depending on the equipment, your options may include: selecting a alternative / lossless format (e.g: PNG), increasing the quality value (closer to 100%), improving the SNR in your sample / scene / capture setup.
